# My substr method not working in js

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between the uncommented lines vs the commented(which is grabbing mm and multiplying by 60 then concatenating with ss)?

```js
function getSeconds(str) {
  // var mm = str.substr(0,2);
  // var ss = str.substr(3,5);
  // return mm*60+ss;
  var nums = str.split(':'),
    mm = +nums[0],
    ss = +nums[1];
  return mm * 60 + ss;
}

getSeconds("13:25");
```

Comment: In your commented code you use `string` instead `str`.

Comment: The second argument to `String.prototype.substr()` is the lenght of the matched substring not the end index, the function which accepts 2 indexes is `String.prototype.substring()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the working example, you are explicitly converting the strings into numbers using the `+` prefix.

In the commented out example, you are not. The minutes are implicitly converted into a number due to the multiplication, however the seconds are simply appended via a string concatenation.

You can resolve that by explicitly converting the two components this example as well:

```js
function getSeconds(str) {
  var mm = +str.substr(0,2);
  var ss = +str.substr(3,2);
  return mm*60+ss;
}

console.log(getSeconds("13:25"));
```

Comment: A more explicit way to convert to number is using the `Number()` constructor, simply using `+` causes confusions as the one the OP had.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to string before using .substring();

```
var myStr = value.toString().substring(2,4);
```